# Hacker rank alternating character in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have been trying to solve Hacker Rank [alternating character problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/alternating-characters) but I got stuck. Can anybody  give explanation or better approach to this problem. Thanks!

```
print("Enter the number of test cases: ")
T = int(input())
line = T
while line > 0:
    test_string = input()
    i = 0
    counter = 0
    while i < (len(test_string)):        
        if (test_string[i - 1] == test_string[i] and len(test_string) > 2):
            test_string = test_string[i:]
            counter += 1                    
        elif (len(test_string) <= 2):
            break
        i += 1
    print (counter)        
    line -= 1
```

Comment: `if (test_string[i - 1] ...` will access `test_string[-1]` on the first iteration.

Comment: You don't need to modify the string as you process it, and it's easier to solve in a bug-free way if you don't.  `test_string = test_string[i:]` is almost certainly wrong, since it ignores the fact that previous iterations may have deleted characters from the front: index `i` is not advancing one character at a time as you (probably) think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only need delete a char if the previous char is the same as the current:

```
T = int(input()) # get how many test cases
for test in range(T): # loop in range T test cases 
    line = input() # get each test 
    prev, changes  = line[0], 0
    for ch in line[1:]:
        if prev == ch:
            changes += 1
        prev = ch            
 print (changes)
```

Or use sum and range getting all groupings:

```
T = int(input())
for test in range(T):
    line = input()
    print(sum(line[i:i+2]  in {"BB","AA"}  for i in range(len(line))))
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It works fine. Even though I understand purpose of ord(a), I don't understand                                                                            if abs(ord(ch) - ord(curr)) != 1: @Padraic

Comment: Got it. Because string can only contain 'A' or 'B' the difference will always be -1 or 1. Thanks again!

Comment: @MilosObradovic, I did not realise there were only A's and B's in each string, you just  need to compare the chars and increase changes if they are equal

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use standard python libs, you can try it with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools as it

def shashank(word):
    new_word = ''.join(char for char,_ in it.groupby(word))
    return new_word, len(word) - len(new_word)

shashank('ABCD') # returns ('ABCD', 0)
shashank('AAABBB') # returns ('AB', 4)
```

This is the Python version of the Linux' command `uniq`.

Comment: Nice, thanks for help! Although your solution is not completely clear to me it's helpful to see different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Python version: via basic coding

**that was easy :)**

```
t = int(raw_input("enter Data \n"))
if t >= 1 and t <= 10 :
    data = []
    for x in xrange(t):
        data.append(raw_input())
    for x in xrange(t):
        if len(data[x])>=1 and len(data[x]) <= 10**5 :
            dcnt = 0
            val = data[x]
            d = len(val)
            for j in xrange(d - 1,0,-1):
                if val[j] == val[j-1]:
                    dcnt += 1
                    val = val[0:j] + val[j+1:10**5]
            print "%s ====> %s, %d deletions" % (data[x], val, dcnt)
        else:
            print "length of string is not withing range :: 1<= length of string <=10**5"
            continue
else:
    print "T is not withing range :: 1<= T <=10"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Count Equal Adjacent Characters - And a Generic Solution

All we need to do is to count equal adjacent characters within the string (sequence of chars) ...

Note, the solution is short, although the following script is very long. I added a general solution and a few examples more. The general solution let's you select the number of allowed adjacent characters. For the given problem that number would be 0. All solutions work with an arbitrary set of characters, hence not only A and B.

The question is now only, how can one easily check, whether a certain number of adjacent characters are the same?

```
"""
Example: 3 different characters A, B and C. Allow for 2 Consecutive Elements,
         hence three equal adjacent elements are not allowed.

  AAABBABAABBCCABAAAB    given string

  AAABBABAABBCCABAAAB    initial string
   AAABBABAABBCCABAAAB   shift by 1
    AAABBABAABBCCABAAAB  shift by 2

    ABBABAABBCCABAAAB    use overlapping elements
    AABBABAABBCCABAAA    check for columns with same character
    AAABBABAABBCCABAA    and count these columns
sum(10000000000000010) = 2 deletions 
"""
```

Ok?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Read in from the command line first the integer we put
    # into the range generator and input than as many strings
    # into the list as the range suggests.
    strings = ['AAAA', 'BBBBB', 'ABABABAB', 'BABABA', 'AAABBB']
    #
    # You can read from the command line by commenting in the
    # next line.
    #
    # strings = [str(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
    #
    #
    # Whenever we find two successive equal strings we
    # need to delete one. Which means, we count this deletions.
    # but we do not perform the deletions, because this
    # was not asked!
    #
    # But how to search for adjacent equal characters, this is
    # what we need to find an algorithm for!
    #
    # Suppose you have the following sequence of
    # characters
    #
    #   AABABAABBBABA
    #
    # Then we create two sequences out of it:
    # One, where we drop the first element, and
    # the other, where we drop the last element
    #
    #   ABABAABBBABA
    #   AABABAABBBAB
    #
    # In other words, we duplicate the sequences
    # and shift one to the right by one char and
    # keep the overlapping elements.
    #
    #   AABABAABBBABA
    #    AABABAABBBABA
    #
    #    ABABAABBBABA
    #    AABABAABBBAB
    #
    # I think you know by looking at the pattern, why
    # I do that.
    #
    # Now, all we need to do is to count the occurences
    # of having the same character at the same vertical
    # position (column) in the two shortened sequences
    #
    # Since I'm lazy and don't like coding myself, I
    # use the len() operation on lists for counting and
    # conditional list comprehension for finding the matches.
    #
    print("---------------- show deletions ----------")
    for string in strings:
        chars = [*string]
        deletions = 0 if len(chars) == 0 else len([b for a, b in zip(chars[1:], chars[:-1]) if a == b])
        print(deletions)
    #
    #
    # If you are interested in the resulting strings, you
    # could do the following: You change the condition in the
    # list comprehension and additionally keep the first element!
    #
    print("---------------- show strings -------------")
    for string in strings:
        if string == '':
            print(string)
            continue
        chars = [*string]
        keep = [a for a, b in zip(chars[1:], chars[:-1]) if a != b]
        # Note: we need to add the first char 'manually', that one
        # is always kept ... given that there is one
        new_string = ''.join((chars[0], *keep))
        print(new_string)

    #
    # Let's solve this on a higher level. Suppose we have an additional
    # parameter telling us how many adjacent characters can be the same.
    # If we set it to zero we end up with the given excercise.
    #
    print("--------------- general solution -------------")
    def deletions(string, n_adjacent=0):
        chars = [*string]
        if len(chars) < n_adjacent:
            return 0
        deletions = sum([len(set(chars[i:i+2+n_adjacent])) == 1 for i in range(len(chars) - (1 + n_adjacent))])
        return deletions, string

    #
    # The given exercise has n_adjacent=0
    #
    n_adjacent = 0
    print(f'------ {n_adjacent + 1} consecutive elements allowed --')
    for string in strings:
        print(deletions(string, n_adjacent=n_adjacent))

    #
    # Let's try a few others now ...
    #
    n_adjacent = 1
    print(f'------ {n_adjacent + 1} consecutive elements allowed --')
    for string in strings:
        print(deletions(string, n_adjacent=n_adjacent))


    n_adjacent = 2
    print(f'------ {n_adjacent + 1} consecutive elements allowed --')
    for string in strings:
        print(deletions(string, n_adjacent=n_adjacent))

    #
    # Note, this algorithm works for arbitrary different
    # characters. Look at the following for example ...
    #
    strings = [
        'AAABBBCCC',
        'ABCCCCCDEEEEEFAGGAGAGABABAAABBBA',
    ]

    n_adjacent = 0
    print(f'------ {n_adjacent + 1} consecutive elements allowed --')
    for string in strings:
        print(deletions(string, n_adjacent=n_adjacent))

    n_adjacent = 1
    print(f'------ {n_adjacent + 1} consecutive elements allowed --')
    for string in strings:
        print(deletions(string, n_adjacent=n_adjacent))

    n_adjacent = 2
    print(f'------ {n_adjacent + 1} consecutive elements allowed --')
    for string in strings:
        print(deletions(string, n_adjacent=n_adjacent))

    #
    # Will it work for n_adjacent = -1, hence 0 elements in a group?
    # We would need to delete all elements.
    #
    n_adjacent = -1
    print(f'------ {n_adjacent + 1} consecutive elements allowed --')
    for string in strings:
        print(deletions(string, n_adjacent=n_adjacent))
```

#### Output

If you run this script, the output looks as follows ...

```
"""
---------------- show deletions ----------
3
4
0
0
4
---------------- show strings -------------
A
B
ABABABAB
BABABA
AB
--------------- general solution -------------
------ 1 consecutive elements allowed --
(3, 'AAAA')
(4, 'BBBBB')
(0, 'ABABABAB')
(0, 'BABABA')
(4, 'AAABBB')
------ 2 consecutive elements allowed --
(2, 'AAAA')
(3, 'BBBBB')
(0, 'ABABABAB')
(0, 'BABABA')
(2, 'AAABBB')
------ 3 consecutive elements allowed --
(1, 'AAAA')
(2, 'BBBBB')
(0, 'ABABABAB')
(0, 'BABABA')
(0, 'AAABBB')
------ 1 consecutive elements allowed --
(6, 'AAABBBCCC')
(13, 'ABCCCCCDEEEEEFAGGAGAGABABAAABBBA')
------ 2 consecutive elements allowed --
(3, 'AAABBBCCC')
(8, 'ABCCCCCDEEEEEFAGGAGAGABABAAABBBA')
------ 3 consecutive elements allowed --
(0, 'AAABBBCCC')
(4, 'ABCCCCCDEEEEEFAGGAGAGABABAAABBBA')
------ 0 consecutive elements allowed --
(9, 'AAABBBCCC')
(32, 'ABCCCCCDEEEEEFAGGAGAGABABAAABBBA')
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the string and if we find the next immediate string similar to the first one then we increment the counter value.

```py
def alterChar(string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)-1):
        if string[i] == string[i+1]:
            count += 1 # Increments if we find next string same
    return count
```

Answer (score -1):

All input/output management aside the only thing you need to do is to go through the input test case and check if a character is the same as the previous. If that's the case you increase the number of suppression.

```
number_test_cases = int(input("Enter the number of test cases: "))              

for idx in range(number_test_cases):                                            
    test_case = input("Test case #{} ".format(idx+1))                           
    suppression = 0                                                             
    for i, c in enumerate(test_case):                                           
        if i < 1:                                                               
            continue                                                            
        if c == test_case[i-1]:                                                 
            suppression += 1                                                    
    print("{} suppression(s) for '{}'".format(suppression, test_case))
```